# No tests were found Test NG

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am facing an issue with testng.
I have a code that I want to debug,  and I put break points in it.
[image]

I try to run debug via the window of intelij and it is not work

[image]

This is my testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
    <test name="Nopackage" >
        <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="login"/>
        </run>
        </groups>

        <packages>
            <package name =".*"/>
        </packages>

    </test>
```

and this is the results:
[image]

this is my project tree and the method I want to run is `getPropValues` that is under `tests` package

Can someone please advise how can I make intllij to let me debug it? 
this is brand new java project using gradle

[image]

I created a new testng.xml and put the path of the class to test, still testng not see the tests

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="All Test Suite">
    <test verbose="2" preserve-order="true" name="testme">
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.PathTest"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

How can I make testng to run a test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a test from your testng.xml file. Simply right-click when you are in testng.xml file and press debug or run

Answer (score 0):

Your `login` group is undefined. Simply do the <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Sorry I do not  understand, where alt enter? I do not have at in any page

Comment: Just click somewhere on the line with `@Test` annotation, do the alt+enter and click on `Add 'login' as a defined test group`

Comment: Sorry still not work, testng refuse to run the test, I even created a new testng.xml and put the class path, and nothing it is not enter the class of the test.